# How to set the data type for an ArrayList during the creation of the object in which it is used

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, types, constructor

I have a Box class object that contains an ArrayList. How can I make it possible to set the data type for this ArrayList when creating the box1 object? For example, only Double from -50.0 to 50.0 for box1 or only Integer from 0 to 10 for box2 or certain Strings for box3.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box1 = new Box("box1");
        box1.addItem(5);
        box1.addItem(3.14);
        box1.addItem("String");
        System.out.println(box1.getItems());
    }
}

class Box {
    String boxName;
    ArrayList<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();

    Box(String boxName) {
    this.boxName = boxName;
    }

    public void addItem (Object item) {
        this.items.add(item);
    }

    public ArrayList getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

I set the ArrayList to an Object data type, but that's not quite right. It is necessary that each object of the Box class have an ArrayList with an individual data type and a list of valid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generics in your code to use specific classes.
For example

```java
class Box<T> {

    String boxName;
    List<T> items = new ArrayList<>();

    Box(String boxName) {
        this.boxName = boxName;
    }

    public void addItem (T item) {
        this.items.add(item);
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can add a new `Predicate` field in a class to use validation.
For example

```java
class Box<T> {

    String boxName;
    List<T> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Predicate<T> validator;

    Box(String boxName, Predicate<T> validator) {
        this.boxName = boxName;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public void addItem (T item) {
        if (validator.test(item)) {
            this.items.add(item);
        } else {
            // do nothing, throw exception, depends on your needs
        }
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

Then you can create your class like this

```java
var box1 = new Box<Integer>("integerBox", item -> item >= 0 && item <= 10);
```

Then, when you try to add elements, for the wrong class, you take a compilation error, Java cannot support that purpose, because there is [strongly typed language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)

```java
box1.addItem(5); 
box1.addItem(3.14); // compilation error
box1.addItem("String"); // compilation error
```

Comment: I think you forget
    `this.validator = validator;`
at Box constructor. Anyway your answer was very helpful, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Generics to specify the data type for the ArrayList in your **Box** class

```
public class Box<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add an item to the box
    public void addItem(T item) {
        // You can add validation here to check the instance of the data type you want
        items.add(item);
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you can use generic type in Java. You can learn more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

For valid values, you can also keep a set of valid values inside your box class that you would pass in the constructor if you don't want to use predicate.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> validVals = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            validVals.add(i);
        }
        Box<Integer> box1 = new Box<>("box1", validVals);
        box1.addItem(5);
        System.out.println(box1.getItems());
        // 20 won't be inserted
        box1.addItem(20);
        System.out.println(box1.getItems());
    }
}

class Box<T> {
    String boxName;
    ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<T> validValues = new HashSet<>();

    Box(String boxName, Set<T> validValues) {
        this.boxName = boxName;
        this.validValues = validValues;
    }

    public void addItem (T item) {
        if (validValues.contains(item)) {
            this.items.add(item);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Generic Class, with the Predicate field to add validations while adding items in the Box Class.

```
class Box<T> {
String boxName;
List<T> boxItems = new ArrayList<>();
Predicate<T> validator;

Box(String boxName, Predicate<T> validator) {
    this.boxName = boxName;
    this.validator = validator;
}

public void addItem (T item) {
    if (validator.test(item)) {
        this.boxItems.add(item);
    }
}

public List<T> getBoxItems() {
    return this.boxItems;
}}


public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Box<Integer> boxA = new Box<Integer>("integer", item -> item >= 0 && item <= 10);
    boxA.addItem(1);
    System.out.println(boxA.getBoxItems());

    Box<Double> boxB = new Box<Double>("double", item -> item >=-50.5 && item<=50.5);
    boxB.addItem(49.3);
    System.out.println(boxB.getBoxItems());
}
```

}